# Ajax file upload with the "Form Plugin" for jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, file-upload

I am using jQuery, and I would like to upload files with Ajax. I have made some searches and found it is not possible.

However, there is one jQuery plugin, [jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#getting-started), which allows us to upload files through Ajax.

It works very well, but I have a special problem. Here is my code:

```
$('#question-form').submit(function() {
    var serialAnswers = '';

    // Create a query string given some fields
    // Format of the query string : answers[0][fr_fr][0]=a1fr&answers[0][fr_fr][1]=2&answers[0][en_uk][0]=a1en&answers[0][en_uk][1]=6&...
    $('#question-answers > div').each(function(idx, elt) {
        $('div[lang]', $(elt)).each(function(idxLang, eltLang) {
            var lang = $(this).attr('lang');
            serialAnswers += 'answers[' + idx + '][' + lang + '][0]=' + $("[answerpart=display]", $(eltLang)).val();
            serialAnswers += '&answers[' + idx + '][' + lang + '][1]=' + $("[answerpart=value]", $(eltLang)).val() + '&';
        });
    });

    $(this).ajaxSubmit({
        datatype: "html",
        type: "POST",
        data: serialAnswers,
        url: $(this).attr("action"),
        success: function(retour) {
            $('#res-ajax').html(retour);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

As you can see, I have to replace the `$.ajax` call by a `$(this).ajaxSubmit()` call, with the same options. Moreover, I have to create a query string (serialAnswers in the code) according to some fields in order to transmit it to the PHP code.

Here is what I used to do when I had no file to upload. I just serialized the form fields and added my query string named serialAnswers:

```
$.ajax({
    datatype: "html",
    type: "POST",
    data: $(this).serialize() + '&' + serialAnswers,
    url: $(this).attr("action")
    success: function(retour) {
        $("#res-ajax").html(retour);
    }
});
```

But my problem is that the form plugin transmits my additional data (the query string) that way (in the PHP file):

```
Array
(
    [question_heading_fr_fr] => something
    [question_heading_en_uk] => nothing
    [question_type] => 5
    [0] => a
    [1] => n
    [2] => s
    [3] => w
    [4] => e
    [5] => r
    [6] => s
    [7] => [
    [8] => 0
    [9] => ]
    [10] => [
    [11] => f
    [12] => r
    [13] => _
    [14] => f
    [15] => r
    [16] => ]
    ....
)
```

According to the documentation, I have to pass a JSON object to the data option, like this:

```
data: { key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2' }
```

But I don't know how to convert my query string to a JSON object and if it would be interpreted as an array on the PHP side.

Is there a solution?

**EDIT**: Even if I use an iframe, I don't know how to add a query string with information which does not come from the form (my `serialAnswer` from the code above).

Comment: [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/)?

Comment: I would prefer not to use flash, if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**: I found a new solution, and it works :)

I have modified the jQuery Form Plugin. Plugin page: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#getting-started. Script: https://github.com/malsup/form/raw/master/jquery.form.js

In order to use this syntax:

```
$('#myform').submit(function() {
    var queryString = 'answers[0][fr_fr][0]=a1fr&answers[0][fr_fr][1]=2&answers[0][en_uk][0]=a1en&answers[0][en_uk][1]=6';

    $(this).ajaxSubmit({
        dataType:  'html',
        data: queryString
    });

    return false; 
});
```

instead of:

```
$('#myform').submit(function() {
    $(this).ajaxSubmit({
        dataType:  'html',
        data: {'key':'value' }
    });

    return false; 
});
```

I have modified the plugin code.

Find this:

```
var n,v,a = this.formToArray(options.semantic);
if (options.data) {
    options.extraData = options.data;
    for (n in options.data) {
        if(options.data[n] instanceof Array) {
            for (var k in options.data[n]) {
                a.push( { name: n, value: options.data[n][k] } );
            }
        }
        else {
            v = options.data[n];
            v = $.isFunction(v) ? v() : v; // if value is fn, invoke it
            a.push( { name: n, value: v } );
        }
    }
}
```

And delete all the `if (options.data)` and its content. A few lines after these ones, find this:

```
var q = $.param(a);
```

And add this right after it:

```
if (options.data) {
    options.extraData = options.data;
    q += '&' + options.data;
}
```

In the function fileUpload(), find this:

```
var extraInputs = [];
try {
    if (s.extraData) {
        for (var n in s.extraData) {
            extraInputs.push(
                $('<input type="hidden" name="'+n+'" value="'+s.extraData[n]+'" />')
                    .appendTo(form)[0]);
        }
    }

    // Add iframe to doc and submit the form
    $io.appendTo('body');
    io.attachEvent ? io.attachEvent('onload', cb) : io.addEventListener('load', cb, false);
    form.submit();
}
```

And replace it by:

```
var extraInputs = [];
try {
    if (s.extraData) {
        var couples = s.extraData.split('&');
        for (var c=0 ; c < couples.length ; c++)
        {
            var couple = couples[c].split('=');
            extraInputs.push(
                $('<input type="hidden" name="'+couple[0]+'" value="'+couple[1]+'" />')
                    .appendTo(form)[0]);
        }
    }

    // add iframe to doc and submit the form
    $io.appendTo('body');
    io.attachEvent ? io.attachEvent('onload', cb) : io.addEventListener('load', cb, false);
    form.submit();
}
```

You now can add a query string thanks to these modifications and uploading an image at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what your looking for but why can't you just do:

```
data: {'key1':$(this).serialize(),'key2': serialAnswers}
```

Then on the PHP side to decode PHP you do

```
json_decode($arr); //Where $arr is whatever the array is that gets passed
```

If you need to pass back a JSON response you just do:

```
json_encode($arr); //Where arr is an array you build within your script
```

I'm assuming this is what you want.

Comment: serialAnswers is the query string. When this data is transmitted to PHP, it is tranformed into an array, so I obtain that : `[key2] => answers[0][fr_fr][0]=something&answers[0][fr_fr][1]=2&answers[0][en_uk][0]=Other&...`
So I cannot decode it with json_decode

Comment: hmm that's a good on you got yourself here.  I haven't got anything right now, but I'll sleep on it and get back to you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/). This is a [Flash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash) based upload plugin. It is easy to implement and supports multiple file upload.

Comment: As I told @ifaour, I was looking for a non-flash solution.
And I have already answered my question, look at the topic ;)